# (Java Swing) JMenuBar não conseguindo colocar as funções no Menu

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, actions, jmenubar

Fala Dev's, tudo bem ?

Estou com um problema na inserção de métodos dentro do meu JMenuBar, até o momento criei dois métodos, um que retorna uma mensageBox perguntando se deseja sair ou não da aplicação e outro que abre a janela sobre da aplicação.
No entanto, nada do que eu tentei funcionou.
Segue código:

```js
// Cria a barra de menu

private void criarMenuBar() {
        
        // define a menu bar (JMenuBar)
        var menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        
        // denine os conteudos (JMenu Ajuda)
        var helpMenu = new JMenu("Ajuda");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_J);
        
        // Submenu dentro de ajuda (Ajuda >> Sobre)
        var about = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
        about.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        about.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
        about.setSelected(true);
        
        // denine os conteudos (JMenu Opções)
        var optionsMenu = new JMenu("Opções");
        optionsMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        
        // Submenu dentro de ajuda (Opções >> Sair)
        var exit = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        exit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        exit.setSelected(true);
        
        // Adiciona os menus (Ajuda e Opções)
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
        menuBar.add(optionsMenu);

        // Adiciona os submenus (Sobre e Sair)
        helpMenu.add(about);
        optionsMenu.add(exit);
        
        // Seta a Barra de menu
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
    
    
    // Esse codigo abaixo que eu quero adicionar nos menus
    
    // Nesse caso ele chama a tela que criei de sobre, se eu tirar o comentario de about.Visible(true); ele já apresenta erro.
    private void aboutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Tela Sobre
        WindowAbout about = new WindowAbout();
        //about.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Nesse caso aqui é a MensageBox que quero colocar no submenu Sair
    private void exitActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // exibe uma caixa de dialogo
        int sair = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Tem certeza que deseja sair ?", "Atenção", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (sair == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Estou usando o intellij para criar a aplicação, e tá se mostrando muito complicado, visto que a criação de interfaces do intellij é um tanto quanto precária.
Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel tambem testar o código, haja visto a complexibilidade da biblioteca swing.

Comment: Tentei colocar aqui mas não consegui 

Comment: Tente reduzir seu codigo a um minimo possivel, não necessariamente é pra coloca-lo inteiro aqui. Apenas o necessário para executar sua janela com o menu que não funciona. Nao precisa de nenhuma outra funcao, ja q sua duvida é somente referente ao Jmenubar, a nao ser q o menu esteja ligado a outras coisas,  porem ai foge do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Então, acontece que eu não sei fazer o esquema pra aparecer a janela aqui no stack 

Comment: Como eu criei a janela usando a GUI Form, não sei fazer ela aparecer aqui 

Comment: Não é pra aparecer janela, é pro código ser executável meso. Se qualquer um copiar esse codigo e colar numa IDE, ele nao roda pq nao ~e um codigo completo. Recomendo que forneça um **[mcve]**, pois se você não fornecer não tem como a gente testar onde está o problema e, consequentemente, não tem como te ajudar. Clique no link e leia para aprender a fazer um.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver esse problema, o problema era que eu estava tentando colocar a action em um local errado, no caso era só eu fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
var exit = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        exit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        exit.setSelected(true);
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int sair = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Tem certeza que deseja sair ?" + "Atenção" + JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (sair == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Nesse caso eu criei a ActionListener logo após a variável, nas minhas tentativas anteriores eu estava criando em baixo e tentando puxar ela pelo nome, o que o Java se recusava a fazer.